# Scala IDE runs whis error "An error has occured. See the log file ...\.metaspace\.log."

Tags: scala, ide

Scala IDE Oxygen September 2017 runs whis error "An error has occured. See the log file ....metaspace.log."

**Versions:**
Scala code runner version 2.12.3
java version "9.0.1"

Log:

```
    !SESSION 2018-01-04 16:05:39.934 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0-vfinal-2017-09-29T14:34:02Z-Typesafe
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-04 16:05:53.607
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

I tryed to set PATH to JDK, JRE, it does't work anyway!
SBT is installed.

How to solve this problem and why this occures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala IDE requires JDK 8, it doesn't work with JDK 9 yet: http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html (in the "Requirements" section, it states "JDK 8").

I can recommend using IntelliJ with the Scala plugin instead - even the community version is much better than any Eclipse-based IDE, including Scala IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

That said, work is still ongoing on full JDK 9+ support in Scala: https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139. This mainly pertains to building the Scala *compiler* itself, though; more than likely, you can compile your Scala code using JDK 11 without problems.

An official webpage with the latest status of Java version compatibility, including links to the relevant GitHub issues, is available here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Comment: @HappyFace - if you are using Ubuntu, this might be handy (easy): https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions

Comment: scala will never support java 9. It only runs on java 8 or on java 11 (in java 8 compatibility mode)